# Driving piezo speakers in the simplest manner

Tags: piezoelectric-effect

I have a few options for the frequency generator side (25-35 Khz). Namely the NE555 or Arduino are some options. These outputs are minimal and I intend to drive the piezo X 4  V<sub>p-p</sub> 12 V. Is the MOSFET the best option on this side? Please any information would be appreciated. I am from a electrical background and trying to learn electronics so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Can you please provide a datasheet of your piezo?

Comment: Hi Jens.Description:
51mm Wateroof Piezoelectric Ultrasonic Speaker.
Rated Noise Power: 5.5Vp-p.
Rated Long Power(Max): 30Vp-p.
Rated Frequency: 2.5-60KHz.
Can be used in repellers, bird repellers, dog training devices, etc.

Specification:
Poduct: Piezoelectric Ultrasonic Speaker
Material: ABS
Rated Noise Power: 5.5Vp-p
Rated Long Power(Max): 30Vp-p
Rated Frequency: 2.5-60KHz
Operating Frequency: 20�5KHz
Rated Sensitivity: 100dB
Operating Temperature: -20~60
Storage Temperature: -30~70
Diameter: Approx. 51mm/2.01inch
Height: Approx. 20mm/0.79inch

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the capacitance of your piezo, but you can abuse a MOSFET gate driver with one inverted and one non inverted output for a start.
The 12 V supply will provide the required Vpp level at the piezo.
R1 limits the peak current and is just a guess.
Some motor driver chips like DRV8220 can handle these frequencies as well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKk31U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another approach uses a tapped inductor or transformer. The output voltage can be contolled by variations of the signal generator duty cycle, values  up to 50% are useful.
However, the resonance frequency of transformer inductance and piezo capacitance should match the input frequency. So this circuit can not be used if a wide frequency range is required.
Do not use this circuit without a connected piezo. High drain voltage peaks can destroy the MOSFET in this case.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzRrZb.png)</sup>

Finally an old school CMOS multivibrator with BJT bridge:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxrCZp.png)</sup>